# clean or dirty price for FixedRateBondHelper

Tags: quantlib

I would like to construct a spot curve from supplied bond prices. I know that the curve has to be constructed from dirty prices (i.e. the ones that include accrued interest). However, from [FittedBondCurve.cpp example posted on quantlib.org](http://quantlib.org/reference/_fitted_bond_curve_8cpp-example.html), it appears that FixedRateBondHelper class is initialized with clean prices.

So, my question is: does it mean that FixedRateBondHelper takes care of computing accrued interest and converting clean price to dirty price? Or is it something that a user should do? I believe it's the former but wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 2):

The helper doesn't, but the fitting algorithm does.  If you look at the [`FittedBondDiscountCurve::FittingMethod::FittingCost::value`](https://github.com/lballabio/quantlib/blob/master/QuantLib/ql/termstructures/yield/fittedbonddiscountcurve.cpp#L213) method, you'll cringe a bit at the nested inner classes, but then you'll see that the model price is calculated by adding the discounted future cash flows and subtracting the accrued amount.

A further note: in recent releases, the bond helpers have been given the possibility to work with quoted dirty prices when bootstrapping a curve (see the last parameter of their constructors, `useCleanPrice`, which defaults to `true` but can be set to `false` to use dirty prices.  However, the `FittedBondDiscountCurve` class is not yet aware of this change, and thus setting `useCleanPrice` to `false` would break the algorithm.  I'll try to fix this in a future release.